Removing an icon from the Show Apps screen in Ubuntu 24.04?
I have deleted the Electrum Bitcoin Wallet from my laptop. The application's icon still displays in the Show Apps screen. If I click on this icon, nothing happens (as expected). How can I remove the icon from the Show Apps window?

When I right-click on the icon, I get a box with options to: New Window, Testnet Mode or Pi to Dash.
The wallet was installed as Flatpack using a tar.gz file. To remove it, I used
sudo apt remove electrum
sudo apt autoremove

When I go to Settings>apps Electrum is listed. When I click on the Electrum listing,and then select App Details, nothing happens. When I click on Open again nothing happens.
I have also searched Synaptic Package Manager and found no packages for the Electrum wallet.
I have also tried to remove the useless icon by installing the Electrum Wallet using the App Center. The app installed (many years out of date) and gave me a second icon (that worked) in the Show Apps window. I then uninstalled the app using the App Center. This removed the second (new working) icon but I was still left with original useless icon.
I tried
flatpak list

and found that flatpak was not installed. I then installed flatpak using
sudo apt install flatpak

and repeated the flatpak list command. This returned an  empty list.

How did you install this app and how did you delete it? Have you restarted the computer since?

what happens if you right click on it? does it show a menu option Show Details from where you can delete it using the bin icon? Which package format was used to install? Snap or Flatpak and detail the exact commands you used to delete it. [edit] your question with the details

as is a Flatpak you should not use apt but instead use flatpak listin order to identify it then use flatpak uninstall --delete-data <app-name> to ensure a complete removal including user data. See this arrticle for further information. I think the reason you didn't see the show details option was because of the way Flatpak was installed in the first place.

I tried the flatpak approach with no result (see the edited OP). As flatpak was not installed before I tried flatpask list, perhaps I didn't use it to install the Electrum wallet.  I am reasonably sure that I used the tar.gz Electrum download to install my Electrum wallet.

The wallet was installed as Flatpack using a tar.gz file doesn't make sene , either you used flatpak or a tar.gz-file. You should look for the responsible .desktop-file. First place to look is ~/.local/share/applications, there you might find the file which needs to be removed.

Thank you @mook765.
I did a global search and found the offending electrum.desktop file in Ubuntu/usr/share/applications. The file was in a hidden directory and read only so I changed directory to where it was located and used sudo rm electrum.desktop to remove it.
Now my problem is solved!
